# Manage multiple sender profiles with trigger sends through Marketing Cloud

Tags: triggered-send

I'm trying to see if we can trigger emails thru API to different From Names. I've already created 3 test Sender Profiles and would like to test that the From Name changes for each upon execution..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to manage multiple sender profiles to trigger via different names/email address thru the api.  Simply change the From address in the Api call.

Examples:

```
{
**"From": {
    "Address": "code@exacttarget.com",
    "Name": "Code@"**
},
"To": {
    "Address": "example@example.com",
    "SubscriberKey": "example@example.com",
    "ContactAttributes": {
        "SubscriberAttributes": {
            "Region": "West",
            "City": "Indianapolis",
            "State": "IN"
        }
    }
},
"Options": {
    "RequestType": "ASYNC"
}
```

}

```
**{
"From": {
    "Address": "Mike@exacttarget.com",
    "Name": "Mike@"
},**
"To": {
    "Address": "example@example.com",
    "SubscriberKey": "example@example.com",
    "ContactAttributes": {
        "SubscriberAttributes": {
            "Region": "West",
            "City": "Indianapolis",
            "State": "IN"
        }
    }
},
"Options": {
    "RequestType": "ASYNC"
}
```

}

Those api calls will appear to come from 2 different email senders.